# How to install pyamf to Windows Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, pyamf

I tried to install pyamf to Python 2.7 x86 on Windows 7 x64.

I used pip install or python setup.py install, but they have the same error.

```
skipping 'cpyamf\amf0.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'cpyamf.amf0' extension
gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c cpyamf\
amf0.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\cpyamf\amf0.o
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

I also tried various versions. I know there is a compiled binary installer for Windows for pyamf version 6. But I'd like to use later version. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you already checked the binaries here? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyamf

Comment: I only know [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAMF/0.6).Thank you!

Comment: Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) to build extension modules.